# Ubuntu partition does not seem to use all free space: how did it happen? and can it be done with Gnome's "Disks"?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

My laptop got shipped from factory with Ubuntu 20.04 (no other OS). Today I noticed that apparently there are only around 56 GB on the disk, but there should be roughly 1TB. Launching Gnome's `Disks` I see this:

[image]

also, this is the output of `df -h`:

```
tmpfs           3.2G  2.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3   53G   11G   40G  21% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop3      255M  255M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/106
/dev/loop2      114M  114M     0 100% /snap/core/13308
/dev/loop1      139M  139M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1536
/dev/loop9      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop6       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop8       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop7      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop4       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop10      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1518
/dev/loop12      52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop11     132M  132M     0 100% /snap/chromium/2011
/dev/nvme0n1p1  513M   28M  485M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G   68K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop13      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
```

and of `fdisk -l`; note how it says "GPT PMBR size mismatch (122879999 != 2000409263) will be corrected by write" at some point:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 138.84 MiB, 145563648 bytes, 284304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 113.91 MiB, 119418880 bytes, 233240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 254.1 MiB, 266436608 bytes, 520384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 81.27 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 55.46 MiB, 58142720 bytes, 113560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 55.55 MiB, 58232832 bytes, 113736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


GPT PMBR size mismatch (122879999 != 2000409263) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL7              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7D8A04D6-18B8-4822-BDDE-11113430DDA4

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      34   1050781   1050748 513.1M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050782   9768967   8718186   4.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 9771008 122877951 113106944    54G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 64.79 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 61.95 MiB, 64933888 bytes, 126824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 131.95 MiB, 138338304 bytes, 270192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 51.4 MiB, 53522432 bytes, 104536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 54.24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

From what I understand the majority of the disk has been reserved as "free space" rather than being given to the Ubuntu partition.

I'd like to ask two questions, the first mostly a curiosity:

1. How could this happen? At the first start-up I simply followed the set-up instructions and answered questions about locale, language, etc. However, the Software centre later asked me to install updated firmware, including bios. Is it possible that this happened after that update? Unfortunately I didn't check the disk space before those updates.
2. I see that the "Disks" program gives me the possibility of resizing the main partition, adding the free space: [image] Is it possible to add the free space using this utility?

I checked the main answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361041) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1354951) (boot from live CD and use gparted), and it sounds like what I should do too, but I wanted to double check that's really the case, since I don't have a dual boot. Some answers, eg to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1269493/1519798), mention `lvextend` but I suppose that doesn't apply to my case.

Finally, another option could be a factory reset, which I think I could make at boot. I was considering this in case something went wrong during the firmware update. But maybe that's overkill?

I'm aware that this question may turn out to be a duplicate (owing to my poor understanding of disk-partition topics); apologies if that's the case. If it's closed as duplicate I'd appreciate some comments explaining how to apply already existing answers to my case. Cheers!

### Update

I went on to follow Organic Marble's advice. By mistake I made a recovery USB rather than a startup USB. Starting the laptop from it automatically restored it to factory settings (luckily I had no data on the laptop, so I did no backup). This actually solved the problem: Now Ubuntu's root partition sees all the free space. Still unclear what caused this glitch to start with.

Comment: If it was setup by someone else, possible they only used a small partition size, thinking you could change it if wanted.  It is setup nicely for changing partitions, gives you a lot of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really odd! Yes, you can resize the partition using Disks, but not if it's mounted (as shown by the star icon in Disks). So you'd have to boot to a live USB to do it.

Back up your data before doing any partition ops.

Comment: Thank you! That's really odd indeed. I'll monitor whether there are new quirks with the disk space and in case do a factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

As you have only a single drive and you can't resize it while it is mounted.
You need to take these steps:

- Take a backup of your data
- Boot with a live USB
- Install [Gparted](https://itslinuxfoss.com/how-to-install-and-use-gparted-on-ubuntu-20-04/) (optional)