# How to boot to a Ubuntu Live USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode while Ubuntu is installed in my Laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, usb

I want to assign unallocated space to Ubuntu partition and following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354951/how-to-assign-unallocated-space-to-ubuntu-partition).

[image]

I installed Ubuntu by USB, and now I cannot find Try Ubuntu mode, when start my laptop, with USB containing Ubuntu I installed before, just 4 choices allowed:

[image]

Where I can open "try Ubuntu" mode now? Thank you so much!

I used Rufus to install to my USB. My Ubuntu Version: 22.04, and when USB is plugged in, this is I found in Ubuntu Home:

[image]

Update: I try to follow the comment, and find this:

[image]

And when I boot USB, it fails.

[image]

Is this because this USB (I cannot format this when using window: disk is written protected, but can format with ubuntu, I think). Should I format the USB and install Ubuntu into it again by Window and restart to open Ubuntu live USB?

---

Comment: It depends on what utility did you use to prepare the USB drive, and what version of Ubuntu you are trying to flash? Thanks.

Comment: @Jags I have already add more info about in my post. Thank you.

Comment: What Ubuntu ISO do you have on USB drive; it maybe using an *revoked* key (thus *Security Violation* error) which means it cannot be booted using Secure-uEFI (but was used to install a system before the key was *revoked*, meaning your installed system got updated keys replacing the *revoked* key).  You've not said what Ubuntu product, nor what release. The fix is to update your thumb-drive with an ISO using a *valid* key; ie. updated version of Ubuntu.  What error is shown (such as *Security Violation*) is firmware specific; ie. refer to your machine manual & code in your error message.

Comment: So now need I format my USB, or is there any software to adjust the key?

Comment: I don't know what OS/release you're using as it wasn't clear in your description. I do note mention of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS which was one ISO that uses a now *revoked* key, the key was updated on installed systems **prior** to the revocation of the key, and it won't impact new installs as Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS media includes the newer keys necessary to boot on Secure-uEFI machines. If the 22.04.1 is your release; this is your issue, and you don't need to format the thumb-drive, just download & write 22.04.3 or *updated* media to it & it'll boot on any Secure-uEFI machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to boot **from the USB drive** to re-enter the live environment.

Since your second image shows an option for "UEFI Firmware Settings", I'm assuming you've installed in UEFI mode. Most likely, when you installed Ubuntu, the installation process modified your system's boot order, and put the new installation as the first option with the highest boot priority, meaning it will always boot by default unless you override it.

While it is possible to use your BIOS setup program to manually modify the boot order and make external drives the default, this is a bad practice for security reasons. It is much preferred to only override it on individual bootups, which is done by entering the boot menu during startup (normally by pressing ESC or one of the F-keys - consult your system's documentation if unsure), which will then list all your drives and allow you to select the USB drive and boot from it.

Comment: I follow your guides but some problems appear that I updated in my post. Can you review it and help me? Thank so much!

Comment: @ThànhAn I believe the "Verification failed" error is to do with secure boot. No idea what you could've changed to the live USB to make it now fail the secure boot check, but easiest course of action would be to turn off secure boot in your BIOS settings, then boot the USB and do what you need to do, then turn secure boot on again if you need it (though you probably won't need it unless you're also running Windows).

Comment: I have already format all partition in ubuntu, but when I open window, USB still appear with 2 drive E and F, but still can not open, required to format, but I cannot format (disk is written protected), and nothing appear for usb in ubuntu. Help me please :((((

Comment: Thank you and everyone so much! I have solved my problem with your guides!